# How to skip the default spring security OAuth2 provider prompt on login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak, spring-oauth2

I have a basic integration with spring boot/security and Keycloak.
When I click on a protected resource I am redirected to the default Keycloak login page, but when I access the /login path on my application I am redirected to this prompt:
[image: OAuh2 provider selection prompt]

As you can see there is only one OAuth2 provider configured and this renders this page completely impractical.

**How can I skip this page or disable the /login path leading to this page?**

**Spring security config:**

Properties file:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=some-client
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-secret=copied_secret
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8180/realms/some_realm
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-name-attribute=preferred_username
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8180/realms/some_realm
```

Security config:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler;
    
    WebSecurityConfig(KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler) {    
         this.keycloakLogoutHandler = keycloakLogoutHandler;    
    }

    @Bean   
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {   
         return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());   
     }

     @Bean  
     public SecurityFilterChain clientFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
         http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
            authorize.requestMatchers(
                 "/",
                 "/themes/**",
                 "/login")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
         );
         http.oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
             .logout(logoutCustomizer ->
                     logoutCustomizer.addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
                             .logoutSuccessUrl("/"));
         return http.build();
     }

     @Bean
     public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                 .build();
     }
}
```

I have tried

1. Disabling the page with `formLogin().disable()`. Also tried replacing this obsolete method with the new one accepting the customizer and disabling it from there.
2. Creating and securing another path for example : loggedInUser to take advantage of the skipping of this page but the path /login still exists and seems like unfinished work.
3. Creating a `@Controller` for `/login` path - controller is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- instead of redirecting to `/login`, you redirect to the URI of the link in the login page (the authorization endpoint on Keycloak, something like `http://localhost:8180/oauth2/authorization/some-client`)
- configure `http.oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2.loginPage("/login"));` and [provide with your own `@Controller`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-login-page) for `/login` and respond with a `302` with `Location` header pointing at at the URI of the link in the login page (same as above)

First option allows to keep the default page if you ever need it.

Comment: As a side note, as you seem to be starting with OAuth2, you might find my [OAuth2 essentials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials) and tutorials useful.